# the_modified_date returns published date

Tags: date, publish

I wanna display modified date instead of published date. I have this code in my theme:

```
echo '<li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="post-date updated">' . get_the_date() . '</span></li>';
```

i changed it to this:

```
the_modified_date('j F Y', '<li><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span class="post-date updated">', '</span></li>');
```

but it still shows the published data.

my post is published on the 1st:
http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2016-08-16/gyDoK2RG.png

and I updated it on the 7th:
http://snap.ashampoo.com/uploads/2016-08-16/pnMvCfmu.png

and the_modified_date() function, displays the published date.
am I doing something wrong? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are using [Parsidate](https://fa.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-parsidate/) plugin to convert dates to Hijri date. The plugin since the current version(2.2.2) returns the published date for both `the_date` and `the_modified_date` functions. This is a bug that i reported it to them. For now, you can use the [wp-jalali](https://fa.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jalali/) plugin instead, that solved the problem for me.